# Rounding a float number in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, rounding

I want to know if there is a simple function that I can use such this sample. 
I have a

```
float value = 1.12345;
```

I want to round it with calling something like

```
float value2 = [roundFloat value:value decimal:3];
NSLog(@"value2 = %f", value2);
```

And I get "1.123"
Is there any `Library` or default function for that or I should write a code block for this type of calculations?

thank for your help in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `NSLog(@"%f", theFloat)` always outputs six decimals, for example:

```
float theFloat = 1;
NSLog(@"%f",theFloat);
```

Output:

```
1.000000
```

In other words, you will never get `1.123` by using `NSLog(@"%f", theFloat)`.

Cut-off after three decimals:

```
float theFloat = 1.23456;
float newFLoat = (int)(theFloat * 1000.0) / 1000.0;
NSLog(@"%f",newFLoat);
```

Output:

```
1.234000
```

Round to three decimals (using `roundf()` / `lroundf()` / `ceil()` / `floor()`):

```
float theFloat = 1.23456;
float newFLoat = (int)(roundf(theFloat * 1000.0)) / 1000.0;
NSLog(@"%f",newFLoat);
```

Output:

```
1.235000
```

Round to three decimals (dirty way):

```
float theFloat = 1.23456;
NSString *theString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f", theFloat];
float newFloat = [theString floatValue];
NSLog(@"%@",theString);
NSLog(@"%f",newFloat);
```

Output:

```
1.235
1.235000
```

Comment: `%f` doesn't output 6 decimals, it _rounds_ to 6 decimals. The actual  floating point value is not so pretty.

Comment: This only works for certain values that have exact representations as binary fractions. It doesn't work in over 90% of cases.

Answer (score 3):

For printing the value use:

```
NSLog(@"value2 = %.3f", value2);
```

Rounding to 3 decimal digits before calculations doesn't really make sense because `float` is not a precise number. Even if you round it to `1.123`, it will be something like `1.122999999998`.

Rules:

1. Usually you round up only to print the result - string formatter can handle it (see above).
2. For precise calculations (e.g. currency), don't use floating point, use `NSDecimalNumber` or fixed point arithmetics.

Comment: Thank for your help but in this sample i should use `float` and also any extra decimal will make some mistake in my specific calculation. but thank for your help also

Comment: I tried NSDecimalNumber and that was also great. thank for your suggest. +1

Comment: @nfarshchi That statement is a contradiction in terms. *Either* you must use float *or* you must have a specific number of decimal places. You *cannot* have both: it is a mathematical impossibility.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers don't have decimal places, they have binary places. Decimal-radix numbers have decimal places. You can't round floating point numbers to specific numbers of decimal places unless you convert to a decimal radix. No routine, method, function etc., that *returns* a floating point value can possibly carry out this task.

Answer (score 0):

Note that "Round" is not necessarily as simple a topic as you think.  For example

[DIY Calculator: Rounding Algorithms 101](http://www.diycalculator.com/sp-round.shtml) lists 16 different methods for rounding a number.

[Wikipedia:Rounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding) covers a lot of the same ground

And Cplusplus  has source code for a bunch of [Rounding Algorithms](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/3638/) that are easy translatable to objective-c

How you want to round will depend on the context of what you are doing with for data.

And I should point out that Stack Overflow already has a [plethora of other questions about rounding in objective-c](http://www.google.com/search?q=round%20decimal%20places%20objective-c%20site%3astackoverflow.com&oq=round%20decimal%20places%20objective-c%20site%3astackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0):

```
//Your Number to Round (can be predefined or whatever you need it to be)
float numberToRound = 1.12345;

float min = ([ [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%.0f",numberToRound] floatValue]);
float max = min + 1;
float maxdif = max - numberToRound;
if (maxdif > .5) {
    numberToRound = min;
}else{
    numberToRound = max;
}

//numberToRound will now equal it's closest whole number (in this case, it's 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do it:

```
float numberToRound = 1.12345f;
float remainder = numberToRound*1000.0f - (float)((int)(numberToRound*1000.0f));

if (remainder >= 0.5f) {
    numberToRound = (float)((int)(numberToRound*1000.0f) + 1)/1000.0f;
}
else {
    numberToRound = (float)((int)(numberToRound*1000.0f))/1000.0f;
}
```

For an arbitrary decimal place, substitute 1000.0f in the above code with

```
float mult = powf(10.0f, decimal);
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
#import <math.h>

float cutFloat( float number, int decimal) {
    number = number*( pow(10,decimal) );
    number = (int)number;
    number = number/( pow(10,decimal) ) ;

    return number;
}
```

Comment: this solution will not round the number. it will cut it to specific decimal place.

Comment: And it won't even do that properly in most cases.