# Same expression returns different values in Objective-C and Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, math, expression

I have this expression. It's in Objective-C.

```
CGFloat x1 = self.frame.size.width / 2 + ((self.frame.size.width - self.borderWidth * 2 - self.graduationOffset) / 2) * cos((6 * i) * (M_PI / 180) - (M_PI / 2));
```

Here are the values for each variable/property. They are all of type `CGFloat`.

`self.frame.size.width` = 200

`self.borderWidth` = 3

`self.graduationOffset` = 10

This whole expression is in a loop that executes 60 times. The value of `i` starts from 0 and goes up to 60. In the code example above, it was 0.

The value of `x1` is **100**.

I converted this expression to Swift like this.

```
let x1 = Double(frame.size.width / 2 + ((frame.size.width - borderWidth * 2 - graduationOffset) / 2)) * cos(Double((6 * i)) * (M_PI / 180) - (M_PI / 2))
```

Passing the same values for the variables. the result I get is **1.17566092718146e-14**.

I tried to break it down and inspect the values separately to figure this out. But that caused only more confusion. Because I got 0 as the final result!

```
CGFloat a = self.frame.size.width / 2 + ((self.frame.size.width - self.borderWidth * 2 - self.graduationOffset) / 2);
NSLog(@"%f", a); // 192.000000
CGFloat b = cos((6 * i) * (M_PI / 180) - (M_PI / 2));
NSLog(@"%f", b); // 0.000000
CGFloat c = a * b;
NSLog(@"%f", c); // 0.000000
```

I tried the same in Swift and got different results.

```
let a = Double(frame.size.width / 2 + ((frame.size.width - borderWidth * 2 - graduationOffset) / 2))
print(a) // 192.0
let b = cos(Double((6 * i)) * (M_PI / 180) - (M_PI / 2))
print(b) // 6.12323399573677e-17
let c = a * b
print(c) // 1.17566092718146e-14
```

I've been going at this all day but can't figure out all this. I guess the way expressions are evaluated is different between Objective-C and Swift? I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: [`NSLog` _rounds_ output to 6 decimals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410791/rounding-a-float-number-in-objective-c), whereas `print(..)` just prints the stored value. The `....e-14` is just classic floating points precision issue (search SO for any of the numerous Q&A on floating point precision). The value is, in essence, `0`, but non-rounded, it will display all its non-precision madness. Make sure not to do equality testing or equality-like testing (e.g. `b>0?`) for floating points numbers.

Comment: Also your first statement vs. the statement broken down *aren't* the same. In the first one, you're multiplying by the `cos(...)`, then adding half the width. In the broken down one, you're adding half the width, then multiplying by the `cos(...)`

Comment: Downvoting on the misleading title "Same expression".  This isn't apples & oranges.  You're comparing via two different logging mechanisms rather than just looking in the debugger.  And you're using two different types, `CGFloat` versus `Double` (and not mentioned whether you're comparing on 32-bit or 64-bit devices).

Comment: @nhgrif You mean it *is* apples & oranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's split your Obj-C code into 3 parts:

```
CGFloat x1 = frameWidth / 2 + ((frameWidth - borderWidth * 2 - graduationOffset) / 2) * cos((6 * i) * (M_PI / 180) - (M_PI / 2));

CGFloat part1 = frameWidth / 2;
CGFloat part2 = ((frameWidth - borderWidth * 2 - graduationOffset) / 2);
CGFloat part3 = cos((6 * i) * (M_PI / 180) - (M_PI / 2));
```

Your Obj-C version is then doing `result = part1 + (part2 * part3)` (I am sure you know that `*` has precedence over `+`) while your additional `Double(...)` cast in the Swift version converts the expression into `result = (part1 + part2) * part3`. Since `part3` is `0` for `i = 0`, the result is clear.

Comment: @Isuru Worth noting that splitting up your logic into multiple lines will not only dismiss the error, but make your code a lot more readable and maintainable. Compact code *purely* for the sake of compact code is rarely a good idea.